# Themochemistry-unknown metal

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

> Pellets of an unknown metal were heated to 95.0 °C and then transferred to a calorimeter containing 175 g of water at 20.0 °C. The highest temperature recorded was 23.6 °C and 96.0 g of the metal were used.
>
> a) Calculate the specific heat capacity of the unknown metal.

(Metal)Hg=Hl(Water)

$$95\ \mathrm g\times c\times \Delta T=175\ \mathrm g\times4.19\ \mathrm{J/(g\ ^\circ C)}\times(23.6\ \mathrm{^\circ C}-20\ \mathrm{^\circ C})$$

I just wanna know how to get the change in temperature for the metal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you are right so far ;

heat given by metal = heat take by water

so neglecting losses of energy ;

$\delta T_{metal} = 95- 23.6$ 
$\delta T_{water} = 23.6-20 $

and by substituting values with correct units in : 
$ m_{metal} c' \delta T_{metal} = m_{water} c \delta T_{water} $

you should get the desired result.